# Importing references from ZOTERO as @online and not @misc

Tags: bibliographies, citing, zotero

I have very recently started using ZOTERO as a tool to import my references to my latex script.
It´s working fine except for the websites I want to import.
Instead of `@online…` they only appear as `@misc…`. So when I want to show the references with the `\printbibliography`, it doesn´t print the url and the date of access. Unfortunately I am not able to edit the bibliography once I imported it.
I checked that the style I saved it in on ZOTERO says website.

I am using the ACS citation style:

```
\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tri.bib}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're getting websites as `@misc` in your exported .bib file from Zotero, you're exporting as BibTex, not as BibLaTeX. Zotero will export them as `@online` for BibLaTeX.

FWIW, if you're using Zotero with Bib(La)TeX, you'll also want to look at the [Better BibTeX add-on](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex) for Zotero